# json_encode don't want to give data (or something else wrong)

Tags: php, jquery

New here and new to coding (kinda). I'm learing by making practical db. Part of code are from tutorials but i understand why and how it works mostly and if not world is full with answers, and most of them here :)

With this particular problem, i believe i just miss something and need fresh look because i'm stuck for 3 days and don't see why it's not working by myself.

**Problem:** Fetch.php was fetching data from sql and give it to `main.php` by `echo $output` (html code). Then I decided I want to make my own paging system and need to get rowcount from `fetch.php` too. So and `json_encode` to fuction and dataType: `json` to caller. And it shoud work but not retrieve any data. It works just fine with other mine function.

So what do i don't see?

P.S. I put alerts before ajax and after and inside success function. First two are triggering. So I assume something wrong with fetch and it don't want to return data.

P.P.S. function fetch_pasutijumi doesn't get anything from `echo json_encode($out);` ... without `dataType:'json',` in ajax request and with `echo ($outputs)` (without using array) it works and html data is given back.

```
function fetch_pasutijumi(query, lim, from)
  {
    $.ajax({
    url:"fetch_pasutijumi.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query, lim:lim, from: from},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
      result = data.outputs;
      $("#result").html(result);
    }
    });
  }


if(isset($_POST["query"]))
   {
      $lim = $_POST["lim"];
      $from = $_POST["from"];
      $search = $_POST["query"];
      $sql = "SELECT job.id AS id, job.red_nr as red_nr, job.name as name, date(job.date) as date, status.name as status_name FROM job LEFT JOIN status ON job.status_id = status.id WHERE job.red_nr LIKE '%".$search."%' OR job.name LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY job.id DESC LIMIT ".$from.", ".$lim;
   }
   else
   {
     $sql = "SELECT job.id AS id, job.red_nr as red_nr, job.name as name, date(job.date) as date, status.name as status_name FROM job LEFT JOIN status ON job.status_id = status.id ORDER BY job.id DESC LIMIT ".$from.", ".$lim;
   } 
$outputs = '
  <table class="tbl_1">
        <tr class="tbl_head">
            <th>Red NR</th> 
            <th>Nosaukums</th>
            <th>Datums</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th><div name="" id=""></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
'; 
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
$total_row = $query->rowCount();


if($total_row > 0)
{
  $outputs .='
    <tr class="tbl_row">
      <td class="td_red_nr"><div id="rednew"><i class="fa fa-plus-square pogas new" id="new"/>Jauns darbs</div></td>
      <td class="td_name"><div id="namenew"></div></td>
      <td class="td_date"><div id="datenew"></div></td>
      <td class="td_status"><div id="statusnew"></div></td>
      <td class="td_buttons1">
      <i style="display:none;" class="fa fa-check-square pogas save" id="new"/>
      <i style="display:none;" class="fa fa-ban pogas cancel" id="new"/>      
      </td>
    </tr>
  ';

  foreach($result as $row)
 {

  $date = date_create($row["date"]);

  $outputs .= '
    <tr class="tbl_row" id="'.$row["id"].'">
      <td class="td_red_nr"><div id="red'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["red_nr"].'</div></td>
      <td class="td_name"><div id="name'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["name"].'</div></td>
      <td class="td_name"><div id="date'.$row["id"].'">'.date_format($date, 'j M Y').'</div></td>
      <td class="td_name"><div id="status'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["status_name"].'</div></td>
      <td class="td_buttons1">
      <i style="display:none;" class="fa fa-pencil-square pogas edit" id="'.$row["id"].'" />
      <i style="display:none;" class="fa fa-check-square pogas save" id="'.$row["id"].'" />
      <i style="display:none;" class="fa fa-ban pogas cancel" id="'.$row["id"].'" />
      <i style="display:none;" class="fa fa-trash pogas delete" id="'.$row["id"].'" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  ';
 }
 $outputs .='</table>';
 $out['outputs'] = $outputs;
 echo json_encode($out);
}
else
{
 $out['outputs'] = $outputs;
 echo json_encode($out);
}
```

Comment: did you console.log(result); what it shows

Comment: You should try learning how to debug your code. This is a lot of code and only little information about where **exactly** something is going wrong and what you've tried to spot that error

Comment: your problem description is vague at best, try to rephrase and clearly explain what it is that doesn't work as you'd expect.

Comment: @AhmedSunny I didn't but i tried alert(result) inside success function and it didn't showed up at all.

Comment: @lovelace function fetch_pasutijumi doesn't get anything from `echo json_encode($out);` ... without `dataType:'json',` in ajax request and with `echo ($outputs)` (without using array) it works and html data is given back.

Comment: add error callback for ajax,  and also you can check what is coming in network tab, click on your request

Comment: Try dumping the `$out` array. Maybe something is wrong there.

Comment: @AhmedSunny ajax error gave in console:
OK
pasutijumi.php:95 parsererror
pasutijumi.php:96 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery-3.3.1.js:8787)
    at done (jquery-3.3.1.js:9255)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.js:9548)
...and i don't understand what it is...anyway...i checked fetch array variable and it's fine and have data i need to give to ajax...but it don't get it

Comment: @Powertieke tried...no it is fine...it is ajax or json_encode (or totally something else)... i don't get it...it is absolutely similar to functions which works good

Comment: just console.log(data); return;  see if you get any data in console. and comment out datatype.  the problem in your json is invalid.

Comment: @AhmedSunny thanks for effort! Problem with this one was in html tags (not in variable but outside php section) which somehow broke json_encode. Strange but fact, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

What a ...

Problem was that `json_encode` somehow don't like `<html>` tag in php file!!! Who could imagine that?

I removed both html tags and it started to work as it should be 3 days ago.
There is no such problem with `echo $something` to ajax.